# Converting a text file with both numbers and characters into numpy arrays and list of strings

Tags: python, list, dataframe, numpy, data-analysis

This seems to be so easy but I cannot solve it and none of the questions no answers I found here are useful for this case.
I have a text file that has valies like this:

```
  -4.040     -75.444 8156.648 1.00 ABC2512
  -4.036     -75.444 8161.305 2.00 ABC2512
  -4.032     -75.444 8174.597 3.00 ABC2512
  -4.029     -75.444 8196.432 4.00 ABC2512
  -4.026     -75.444 8212.521 5.00 ABC1240
  -4.012     -75.443 8268.073 11.00 ABC1240
  -4.009     -75.443 8280.411 12.00 ABC1240
```

Eventually, I want to have 4 different numpy arrays from the first four columns, and a list of strings from the last column. It could be nice if I also could have a header file as the frist row.
So far, I tried to convert it to a datarame like this:

```
f = open(irh_file)
g = pd.DataFrame(list(f))
```

but then I cannot split the columns, because the delimiters are both tabs and spaces.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `pd.read_csv` to load the data into dataframe:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("out1.txt", sep=r"\s+", header=None)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
       0       1         2     3        4
0 -4.040 -75.444  8156.648   1.0  ABC2512
1 -4.036 -75.444  8161.305   2.0  ABC2512
2 -4.032 -75.444  8174.597   3.0  ABC2512
3 -4.029 -75.444  8196.432   4.0  ABC2512
4 -4.026 -75.444  8212.521   5.0  ABC1240
5 -4.012 -75.443  8268.073  11.0  ABC1240
6 -4.009 -75.443  8280.411  12.0  ABC1240
```

---

Then:

```py
arr_1 = df[0].values
print(arr_1)

arr_5 = df[4].tolist()
print(arr_5)
```

Prints:

```
[-4.04  -4.036 -4.032 -4.029 -4.026 -4.012 -4.009]
['ABC2512', 'ABC2512', 'ABC2512', 'ABC2512', 'ABC1240', 'ABC1240', 'ABC1240']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do as:

with `pandas`

```
import pandas as pd
colnames = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
data = pd.read_csv('irh_file.txt', delim_whitespace=True, names=colnames)
>>> data
       a       b         c     d        e
0 -4.040 -75.444  8156.648   1.0  ABC2512
1 -4.036 -75.444  8161.305   2.0  ABC2512
2 -4.032 -75.444  8174.597   3.0  ABC2512
3 -4.029 -75.444  8196.432   4.0  ABC2512
4 -4.026 -75.444  8212.521   5.0  ABC1240
5 -4.012 -75.443  8268.073  11.0  ABC1240
6 -4.009 -75.443  8280.411  12.0  ABC1240
```

with `numpy`

```
import numpy as np
np.loadtxt('file.txt',dtype='str') 
# slice numerical col into an array as 
num = np.array(data[0:5,1:-1], dtype=float) 
#string col
lst_col = np.array(data[:-1,-1], dtype=str)
```

Comment: actually how do you then make each of the columns into numpy arrays and the last column into a list of strings?

Comment: @Travis_Dudeson  I have not tried before maybe I'll do.. `data = np.loadtxt('file.txt',dtype='str')` then slice numerical col into an array as `num = np.array(data[0:5,1:-1], dtype=float)` and string col as `lst_col = np.array(data[:-1,-1], dtype=str)` I think you should review/read this [NumPy Cheat Sheet](https://www.datacamp.com/cheat-sheet/numpy-cheat-sheet-data-analysis-in-python)